# Is bugzilla a bug tracker or debugger?

Tags: debugging, bugzilla

when I try to search for details about bugzilla most of the sources are saying it is a bug tracker...Please let me know the difference between debugger and bug tracker...And also throw some light on bugzilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Bug Tracker:**

A bug tracker or [bug tracking system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system) is an application that keeps the records of reported bugs in a software development project.

A bug tracking system generally consists of database and user interface. Backend database is used to store the records of known bugs which include bug's description, severity, expected and actual behavior of the program, steps to reproduce the bug, concerned developer or tester etc. In a software development project, a bug-tracking system is also used to generate bug reports to measure the productivity of programmers at fixing bugs.

Bug tracking systems are included in integrated project management systems. This approach allows a record tracking and communication between testers and developers. Bug records are required in fixing bugs in newer product versions, generation of product knowledge base and release notes.

> **Debugger:**

[Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) is a software application, often included in an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), used to test and debug other program (target program) which is being developed in IDE. Developers use the debugger tool to run the program in steps and thus it becomes easier to find out the code in a program responsible for a particular bug.

Debuggers also help in breaking/pausing the program to verify the current state at some event by means of a breakpoint and tracking the values of variables at that state.

**[Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)** is a Web-based general-purpose bugtracker and testing tool originally developed and used by the Mozilla project, and licensed under the Mozilla Public License.

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla is a software issue management tool, not a debugger.

[image]